# can't send value to database postgresql with Django and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, django, ajax, postgresql

i'm try use Ajax send correctAnswers to postgresql with Django but it error.
I don't know where I missed it.

```js
function checkAnswers() {
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  var correctAnswers = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
    var radios = document.getElementsByName("question" + (i + 1));
    var questionCol = document.getElementsByClassName("col-12")[i];
    var isCorrect = false;
    for (var j = 0; j < radios.length; j++) {
      if (radios[j].value == questions[i].correctAnswer && radios[j].checked) {
        correctAnswers++;
        isCorrect = true;
        break;
      }
    }
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =
    "คุณได้คะแนน " + correctAnswers + " / " + questions.length;
  var backButton = document.createElement("input");
  backButton.setAttribute("type", "button");
  backButton.setAttribute("value", "กลับไปหน้าหลัก");
  backButton.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-primary center1");
  backButton.setAttribute("onclick", "location.href='User-page.html'");
  document.getElementById("quizForm").appendChild(backButton);

  $.ajax({
    url: "/submit_quiz/",
    type: "POST",
    data: { correctAnswers: correctAnswers },
    success: function (response) {
      console.log("ส่งค่าไป data base สำเร็จ");
    },
  });
}
```

It has no ajax response.

Comment: Do you really want to check the correct answers on the client side? Better send all answers to django and check there wether they are correct or not. Never put your business logic on the client side.

Comment: And for anybody to really answer your question you have to provide the django view as well.